Deleting organizational account under Windows 10
I want to delete a 'work or school account' that I once added using the institutional email address, but which now has become obsolete (Windows 10). There does not seem to be a 'delete account' option; if I click 'Manage' a browser opens with options at Microsoft where I also cannot delete the account from my system. What do I need to do to get rid of it?


Is the same account mentioned in other subsections under 'Accounts'? I don't remember fully now, but last time I had to remove the account, I think it was under "Access work"?

@grawity_u1686 Thanks, yes see the accepted answer below. I hadn't searched for it there.

I just booted up a VM and tested.
I was succesful in removing my work account by going to:

Settings
Accounts
Access work or school
Disconnect --> Press "Yes" (This seems to disconnect the ability for Microsoft apps to sign in)
Disconnect (again) --> Press "Yes" (This removes the account entirely and should now be gone under "Email & accounts")



Finally I know how to get rid of it. Thanks!
